# Wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I need to create a dash board widget in wordpress.It is possible to create a dash board widget?If yes,In which folder we need to save the widget creation file.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) has extensive information on how to register everything. It wouldn't matter where the file is as long as it's in the plugins directory, and your file needs to use the proper functions to register functions inside it as a dashboard widget.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get it :)

http://rick.jinlabs.com/2009/02/01/how-add-options-to-your-wordpress-27-dashboard-widgets/

along with the link the above article links to in the beginning.